# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer android

Tags: android, oauth, twitter-oauth

Am using twitter integration using SocialLib project. But the thing is constantly am getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer
```

at the line

```
httpOauthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
```

and my imports are:

```
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthNotAuthorizedException;
```

and the jars i used and downloaded from:http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/downloads/list

How to reslove this?

Hanks

Comment: Here's a solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623864/oauth-with-android - @Phix
Helped to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is jarlibrary: http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/downloads/detail?name=signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar&can=2&q= You should add it to your project as a external jar.

Comment: The jar I have pasted is the additional one. I had similar problem and when I have added this jar the issue gone.

Comment: @chinna_82 Thank you for your downvote nevertheless I have resolved in this way my own issue.

Comment: +1 as it worked for me. Can you explain what is the additional thing in this jar?