# OAuth with Android

Tags: android, oauth, signpost, yelp

I am attempting to access the Yelp API. I have obtained my keys and have read about 40 articles explaining what I need to do and I have attempted everything. The key and what not are valid. I am getting the following:

```
05-16 17:39:54.955: E/AndroidRuntime(538): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer
```

I have imported the commons-codec-1.6 jar, the signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar, and the signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar.

I am still getting the error message. Any help?

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;


/**
 * Example for accessing the Yelp API.
 */
public class Yelp {
  private String consumerKey = "";
  private String consumerSecret = "";
  private String token = "";
  private String tokenSecret = "";

  /**
   * Search with term and location.
   *
   * @param term Search term
   * @param latitude Latitude
   * @param longitude Longitude
   * @return JSON string response
   */
  public String search(String term, double latitude, double longitude) throws OAuthMessageSignerException, OAuthExpectationFailedException, OAuthCommunicationException {



    try {
        OAuthConsumer myConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
        myConsumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, tokenSecret);

        String urlToPost = "http://api.yelp.com/v2/search";
        Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        myMap.put(OAuth.OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, consumerKey);
        myMap.put(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, token);
        myMap.put(OAuth.OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD, "HMAC-SHA1");
        myMap.put(OAuth.OAUTH_SIGNATURE, tokenSecret);
        myMap.put(OAuth.OAUTH_TIMESTAMP, Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L));
        myMap.put(OAuth.OAUTH_NONCE, "asdf");

        urlToPost = OAuth.addQueryParameters(urlToPost, myMap);

        HttpURLConnection myCon = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(urlToPost)).openConnection();
        myConsumer.sign(myCon);

        myCon.connect();
        return myCon.getResponseMessage();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Go to Project -> Properties, and under your Java Build Path -> Order and Export tab make sure those JARs are checked.

And, just for future reference, if those are your real keys, I would make sure to **not** put them on a public website.  Just sayin.

Comment: <3 thank you. Saved me many more hours of frustration over something so simple that I overlooked

Answer (score 0):

I also face same problem in Android app. when i use **signpost-core-1.2.1.2**  but It was not able to resolve **CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer** . I download it from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsignpostcommonshttp41211jar.htm

It worked.